# NServiceBus Messages and Encapsulation

Tags: message, nservicebus, deserialization

I hope this is not an idiot question... my brain is so full of new stuff it hurts.

I'm attempting to get to know NServiceBus a little better.

My message classes look like this:

```
public class Address // value object
    {
        public readonly string AddressLine1;
        public readonly string AddressLine2;
        public readonly string AddressLine3;
        public readonly string City;
        public readonly string Country;
        public readonly string PostCode;

        public Address(string addressLine1,
                       string addressLine2,
                       string addressLine3,
                       string city,
                       string country,
                       string postCode)
        {
            AddressLine1 = addressLine1;
            AddressLine2 = addressLine2;
            AddressLine3 = addressLine3;
            City = city;
            Country = country;
            PostCode = postCode;
        }
    }
```

Problem is NServiceBus serializer cannot deal with it (understandably so) and i end up having to revert to auto properties. I can live with it for this learning exercise... but is there a way to use the message class above?

I thought I would ask instead of delving into NServiceBus source code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it'll work if you expose get/private set properties rather than fields.

Comment: Thanks Udi, I'll look into that - it's preferable at this stage to including the Json Serializer. I'll upvote when confirmed. Awesome framework by the way!

Answer (score 2):

I have not used NSB for some time, but i remember that there was a [contrib module](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus-Contrib/) that contains a [JsonSerializer](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus-Contrib/blob/master/src/Serializers/Json/README.markdown) based on [Newtonsoft Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) library.

The json.net lib supports (de)serialization of objects like the one you describe. You can find more details about what is supported by serialization libraries [here](http://www.erata.net/net/net-serialization-choices/).

Comment: I'll look into the Json serializers (Raven / Newtonsoft) since they're already in the project. Thanks.

Comment: #lulian - hey I moved the answer to #Udi below as it seems "more correct" I guess seeing it's baked into the framework. Hope this is ok.

Comment: When talking about NSB always trust Udi :)